# Vote / Discuss: Consolidate New York tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have [new-york](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york), [new-york-city](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york-city), and [new-york-state](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york-state). Can we get rid of [new-york](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york)?

Comment: When you say "get rid of" do you just want to burninate (remove all occurrences) or blacklist (prevent the tag ever being used)?

Comment: I just completed disambiguating any remaining questions tagged [tag:new-york] to [tag:new-york-city] or [tag:new-york-state] (occasionally both).  If there are any issues I recommend starting a new question to resolve them.

Comment: @PolyGeo I think it would be useful to update the usage guidance for these tags. If I had a question about someone in New York City, then I still wouldn't be sure whether I should tag the state or city.

Comment: @vervet I just updated the tag excerpts for [tag:new-york-city] and [tag:new-york-state] so I'm hoping that you and others can see if they look better.  As always feel free to improve them further.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, merge the ambiguous [new-york](/questions/tagged/new-york) tag into [new-york-state](/questions/tagged/new-york-state) and remove any New York synonyms.

Keep specific [new-york-city](/questions/tagged/new-york-city) and [new-york-state](/questions/tagged/new-york-state).

Comment: I think we need to clarify what is meant by "get rid of" - is it burninate, blacklist, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Sort out a more generalised/consistent approach to geographic tags and then apply it to solve this problem.

Comment: I think we have already achieved considerable consensus on geographic tags at http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/63/19

Comment: @PolyGeo, And I think that question just demonstrates that we all agree there should be geographic tags. It also demonstrates that we don't know how they should be organised. If we had consensus this question wouldn't have needed to be asked.

Comment: I guess I am reading it as countries - yes, state/province/county (when one level below country) - yes, cities - only in exceptional circumstances (so far NYC, London, Bristol have been discussed and Liverpool has also been used).  I've noticed continents (e.g. Europe, Asia) used a few times which seems OK and the occasional historical region like Bessarabia.  I think we are already seeing a high level of consistency with NYC/NYS needing slight clarification.  Georgia (country) and Georgia (US state) probably needs discussion sometime - perhaps [tag:georgia-country] and [tag:georgia-us-state].

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that we need to do anything on this one because [new-york](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york) is already a synonym of [new-york-city](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york-city), and we have a separate tag for [new-york-state](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york-state).

If any were to try and add a [new-york](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york) tag (or edit one with an existing [new-york](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york) tag) then they would find that, upon saving their question, the tag would change to [new-york-city](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york-city).

The disambiguation was performed after [this answer](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1862/19) to another question.

The reason that I think we need to have [new-york](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york) as a synonym to [new-york-city](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york-city) is:

1. We do not yet have [A real solution to ambiguous tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125234/a-real-solution-to-ambiguous-tags)  If I were to choose [new-york](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york) I would love to be asked "Do you mean [new-york-city](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york-city) or [new-york-state](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york-state)?" but that functionality has not been implemented.
2. Burninating and then blacklisting [new-york](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york) so that it cannot be used requires a multi-step process which seems like overkill for its level of inconvenience: [How should we make tag blacklist requests?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239189/how-should-we-make-tag-blacklist-requests)
3. If we do not blacklist the [new-york](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york) tag after deleting all occurrences then it will keep coming back each time someone types it in again.
4. I think making [new-york](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york) be a synonym to [new-york-city](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york-city) OR [new-york-state](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york-state) works well, and to a non-US user like me when we say "New York" we mean the "Big Apple" and are barely aware that there is a state of the same name which is why I chose the "city" over the "state" as the "default".

Comment: @JanMurphy I've expanded upon my answer to explain why I believe a synonym is the best way forward while emphasizing that I understand the distinction between the city and state and the importance of making that distinction in our questions.

Comment: I know it would likely require some clean-up but going the synonym route I think we should default to the larger geographic area vs. the city as it will also cover the city. A similar situation would be Washington or Washington State.. when you say Washington do you mean Washington D.C. or the state? By default I think we should mean Washington state.

Answer (score 0):

The plain tag [new-york](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york) should redirect to [new-york-state](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york-state) not [new-york-city](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york-city). If someone is asking a question about a locality in New York State, the answers about how to do research in New York State will hold true for all counties except the five boroughs of New York, and sometimes three other upstate counties. Most of the time someone who wants to tag a question [new-york](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york) they will be asking about New York State.

However, I still assert that New York City needs its own tag because of the unique circumstances in finding New York City records. Answers for New York State in the modern period will not apply to the five boroughs of New York City after the consolidation.

People considering blacklisting [new-york](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york) should consider that we would have to ask one of the developers to do it -- see [What does it mean to “burninate” a tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/what-does-it-mean-to-burninate-a-tag).

Answer (score -1):

No change. Keep them all. 
[new-york](/questions/tagged/new-york), [new-york-city](/questions/tagged/new-york-city), and [new-york-state](/questions/tagged/new-york-state) with no aliases.

Answer (score -3):

No keep general [new-york](/questions/tagged/new-york), and get rid of specific [new-york-city](/questions/tagged/new-york-city) and [new-york-state](/questions/tagged/new-york-state).

Comment: There is an argument for having a separate tag for New York City.  See  [Geographic Tags](http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/1862/1006).  Answers that apply to New York State are NOT applicable to NYC.

Comment: @JanMurphy I would agree, but if question applies to both it should have both New York tags.